# Linq Select as for loop condition C#

Tags: c#, linq

So, I have a list of integers called itemIds and a list of objects called items, how can I rewrite this :

```
 List<int> itemIds;
 List<object> items;

 for (itemIds.Select(old => (!items.Any(i => i.itemId == old))))
    {
          ItemService.ItemDeleteById(old);
    }
```

Now it fails, it asks for ";" after the last paranthesis of the for and it doesn't recognize the old variable.I want to delete the items that meet that condition. Thanks !

Comment: `for` requires a start condition, end condition, and an increment step, you are missing 2 of the 3.

Comment: @RonBeyer you said it better than I did.

Comment: The answers below will work for your current pattern.  My question is if itemIds appear to be unique enough for deletion, why are you storing them in a `List` and not a `Dictionary`?

Comment: @DragandDrop The MSDN is dead, that's Microsoft Docs

Comment: And the mandatory reference to the Microsoft Docs: [for statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for). 
The correct  syntax is : `for (<initializer>; <condition>; <iterator>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `foreach` instead of `for` and `Select` doesn't receive a predicate true/ false, use `Where` instead

```
foreach (var item in itemIds.Where(old => !items.Any(i => i.itemId == old)))
    {
          ItemService.ItemDeleteById(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach`. Also use `.Where()` instead of `.Select()`:

```
foreach (var itemId in itemIds.Where(old => !items.Any(i => i.itemId == old)))
{
    ItemService.ItemDeleteById(itemId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you hashed itemIds, you'll probably have a more performant loop:

```
HashSet<int> itemIds;
List<object> items;

foreach (var item in items.Where(i => itemIds.Contains(i.itemId))
{
   ItemService.ItemDeleteById(item.itemId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as:

```
foreach(var x in itemsIds.Where(old => items.Contains(old)){
        ItemService.ItemDeleteById(x);
    }
```

EDIT: Outspeedded by Parrish Husband